# lm() con error "undefinded columns"

Tags: r

Estoy empezando con los modelos lineales en R. Tengo un dataset compuesto por 32 observaciones de 4 variables. Una de elllas es "sexo", que divide entre hombres y mujeres. Para los hombres hay 14 observaciones y para las mujeres, 18. He recodificado esta variable, que antes aparecía como M y F, por 0 y 1.

Al intentar hacer un modelo lineal que solo contenga a las mujeres de la siguiente manera:

lm(Metabol ~ Gastric + Sex, data = alcoholic[alcoholic$Sex == 1])

obtengo el siguiente error:

Error in `[.data.frame`(alcoholic, alcoholic$Sex == 1) : undefined columns selected

¿a qué puede ser debido?

¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, la selección de filas que haces, está mal, debiera ser `alcoholic[alcoholic$Sex == 1, ]`, nota la coma. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Al incluir la coma, lanza otro error. Es el siguiente: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: Alguno de los `factor` que usas en el  modelo solo tienen un nivel o son NA, si es correcto esto, entonces no sirven como variable explicativa y los podrías quitar.

Comment: Las variables Metabol y Gastric son numéricas y no tienen ningún NA, y los otros dos factores, sex y alcoholic son categóricos con dos niveles (0 y 1).

Comment: Si, pero tus datos para el modelo, al menos como muestras en tu pregunta, son `alcoholic[alcoholic$Sex == 1, ]` con lo cual `Sex` solo va a tener un nivel, o está mal la selección o la variabla en la formula.

Comment: ¡Claro! Acabo de entender mi error y tu anterior comentario. ¡Muchísimas gracias!